# Shearing matrix with different basis

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

Given a  vector $\vec{u}$ and a vector $\vec{v}$. We can now shear $\vec{u}$ to $\vec{v}$. How can we determine the shear Matrix $S$ in the standard basis?

My approach would be first determining this shear matrix with respect to another basis, namely the basis $\{\vec{w}_1,\vec{w}_2,\vec{u}\}$, where $\vec{w}_1, \vec{w}_2$ are eigenvectors of $S$. This would give a matrix $S'$.

To calculate $S$ (in terms of the standard basis), I would use the "change of basis matrix $P$ and its inverse $P^{-1}$.

However, I was told there was a simpler method, but I can't seem to find it anywhere. Any help?

Comment: You list three vectors in your basis. Are you working in a three-dimensional space, then?

Comment: Yes! It's for working with graphics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is somewhat simpler than the procedure you’ve described, but uses pretty much the same underlying idea.

Assume that we’re working in $\mathbb R^2$. The shear you describe is in the direction of $v-u$. Assuming that $u$ and $v$ are linearly independent, we can take as a basis $u$ and $v-u$. The shear maps $u$ to $v$ and $v-u$ to itself, so recalling that the columns of a transformation matrix are the images of the basis vectors, we can construct the shear matrix as $$S=\begin{bmatrix}v&v-u\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}u&v-u\end{bmatrix}^{-1}$$ which can be computed via row-reduction if you want to avoid the matrix inversion and multiplication.

To generalize this to higher dimensions, observe that the shear acts only in the plane of $u$ and $v$, so you can simply fill out the rest of the two matrices with any basis for the orthogonal complement of their span, which is invariant under this shear. In $\mathbb R^3$ this means that you can use $u\times v$ as the third column of the two matrices above.